# Limit internet speed to make it stable

Tags: windows-10, networking

My friend just replaced her dead motherboard with a new one from the same generation, as she had no money for a processor upgrade. After plugging the new board to her router, she is now having instability issues with her connection.

After some research, we found out that issue seems to be related to the motherboard's ethernet adapter being a 10/100Mbps one and her connection speed being 200Mbps up/down.

Is there a way to limit her computer's connection speed in order for it to be stable again?

Comment: Yeah;  You have misdiagnosed the problem

Comment: The computer's speed limitation should use just what Internet speed it can. Speed does not "push", so look to Driver problems for stability issues. Run the computer manufacturer's driver update app and update all drivers. See if driver update returns stability.

Comment: Bet she has a realtek network card onboard. Those things are notoriously crap. Sometimes getting a new driver helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in speed would not cause instability.  The problem is most probably something else.  Since the motherboard is what is new, it or something connected to it is likely the problem.  Make sure you have the latest BIOS, firmware, and drivers for all the components of the motherboard.  You should be able to find them in the motherboard manufacturer's website.

Without thorough testing, it would be hard to determine the issue, but it would help to test individual components one at a time.  Replace the ethernet cable with one you know works.  Perhaps the onboard network card is bad.  You can purchase a new ethernet card online very cheap.

I would also contact the ISP and have them do a test.  Not likely the issue, but it wouldnt hurt.

If you have done all this and its still not working properly, I would say the motherboard you purchased is bad.